# Does `phantomjs` `resourceTimeout` actually work?

Tags: phantomjs

I use `phantomjs` with slow proxy. I use `resourceTimeout` to force `phantomjs` to wait for resources downloading and not to fail.

I set `resourceTimeout` = 120000 (2 minutes). However, `phantomjs` throws `onResourceError` after some seconds of waiting for proxy (I am 100% sure proxy doesn't interrupt connection, phantomjs does it).

So, if `phantomjs` throws `onResourceError` much faster that timeout may appear, the question is: does `resourceTimeout` actually work and what does this setting mean?

Comment: maybe you should increase connection timeout too

Comment: Can you advice how to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry, just checked the code and realized that I use only resourceTimeout param. Have no ideas now. What does error description tell ? https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/getting-to-the-bottom-of-why-a-phantomjs-page-load-fails/

Comment: The error is `Operation cancelled`. This error never appear on fast mode (I use test proxy where I can put artificial delay for each web request). However, with some level of delay this error is guaranteed to appear.

Comment: for now it really looks like phantomjs ignores resource timeout value. if I were you, I'd check phantomjs source code to verify that

Comment: do you have any progress here?

Comment: No, I switched from phantomjs to another emulation technology. I don't care about development of phantomjs, as soon as it is not OK for me, I just don't use it.

Comment: what technology did you choose? :)

Comment: I switched to write C++ program that emulates my specific website. Unfortunatelly, I was unable to find browser emulator that can run on 1000+ threads and use proxies effectivelly.